# execution order of loops in C

Tags: c++, c

this is probably a very noob question but I was what the result of this would be:

```
int someVariable = 1;

while (callFunction(someVariable));

    if (someVariable = 1) {
        printf("a1");
    } else {
        printf("a2");
    }

callFunction (int i) {
    while (i< 100000000) {
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

so when you hit the while loop

```
while (callFunction(someVariable));
```

does a thread wait at that loop until it finishes and then to

```
if(someVariable == 1) {
    printf("a1");
} else {
    printf("a2");
}
```

or does it skip and move to the if condition, print "a2" and then after the loop has finished goes through the if condition again?

**UPDATE:** This isn't ment to be valid c code just psuedo, maybe I didn't word it right, basically what I'm trying to figure out is what the different between a loop like `while (callFunction(someVariable));` is vs

```
while (callFunction(someVariable)){}
```

i also changed the bolded part in my code i.e ** int someVariable = 1; **, I was doing an endless loop which wasn't my intention.

Comment: Please, indent your code. Also this code is not valid C++, because `callFunction` has not return type specified.

Comment: `callFunction` always returns `1`. The `while` loop never terminates. None of `"a1"` or `"a2"` ever gets printed.

Comment: This `if(someVariable = 1) ` sets the variable to 1. You probably intended `if(someVariable == 1)`.

Comment: We still want to know what 'VM model' meant!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

> basically what I'm trying to figure out is what the different between a loop like `while (callFunction(someVariable));` is vs `while (callFunction(someVariable)){}`

No practical difference.  `;` delimits an empty statement, `{` `}` is a scope without statements.  Any compiler can be expected to produce identical code.

Of course, if you want to do something in each iteration of the loop, `{` `}` creates a "scope" in which you can create types, typedefs and variables as well as call functions: on reaching the '}' or having an uncaught exception, the local content is cleaned up - with destructors called and any identifiers/symbols use forgotten as the compiler continues....

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

This...

```
callFunction(int i){
     while (i< 100000000){
         i++;
     }
     return 1;
}
```

...just wastes a lot of CPU time, if the compiler's optimiser doesn't remove the loop on the basis that it does no externally-visible work - i.e. that there are no side-effects of the loop on the state of anything other that "i" and that that's irrelevant because the function returns without using i again.  If always returns "1", which means the calling code...

```
while (callFunction(someVariable));
```

...is equivalent to...

```
while (1)
    ;
```

...which simply loops forever.

Consequently, the rest of the program - after this `while` loop - is never executed.

It's very hard to guess what you were really trying to do.

To get better at programming yourself - understanding the behaviour of your code - you should probably do one or both of:

- insert output statements into your program so you can see how the value of variables is changing as the program executes, and whether it's exiting loops
- use a debugger to do the same

Answer (score 6):

The code inside a function is executed sequentially, by a single thread. Even if you send an other thread to your function it will execute it sequentually as well.

This is true to 99% of programming languages now days.

Comment: Interestingly which languages are in the other 1%? So I can avoid... ;)

Comment: @Nim: (pure) functional languages typically don't have these strict sequential semantics.. (but then they also don't allow you to write code like this in the first place). And there are languages designed specifically for parallelism and message passing as well, where nearly everything runs in parallel until some synchronization point is reached. Only imperative languages really have the "do this; then do that" kind of semantics

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains an endless loop before any output:

```
while (callFunction(someVariable));
```

Did you mean for the `;` to be there (an empty loop), or did you
mean something else?  Not that it matters: `callFunction`
always returns `1`, which is converted into `true`.  (If you
really want the loop to be empty, at least put the `;` on
a separate line where it can be seen.)

If you do get beyond the `while` (because you modify some code
somewhere), the `if` contains an embedded assignment; it's
basically the same as:

```
if ( (someVariable = 1) != 0 )
```

Which is, of course, always true.  (Most C++ compilers should
warn about the embedded assignment or the fact that the `if`
always evaluates to true.  Or both.)

Comment: would there be a difference between while(1); and while(1){} ?

Comment: @Saad No.  Neither is very readable.  `while` controls one or more statements, which should be written on a separate line, indented so that the reader can see what it controls.

Answer (score 0):

If your loop completes (it would be sequentially yes, if you fix it), it will print 'a1', since you're doing an assignment in the if, which will always return 1, which evaluates to 'true' for conditionals.